# R: Sequential Ordering With Adjacent Number

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to order a sequence in R with all of the numbers adjacent and ties counted the same.  For example

```
Aorder(1,1,40,50,2,40,2)
[1] 1 1 3 4 2 3 2
```

In contrast to order:

```
order(c(1,1,40,50,2,40,2))
[1] 1 2 5 7 3 6 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be more efficient than using `factor`:

```
x <- c(1,1,40,50,2,40,2)

match(x, sort(unique(x)))
#[1] 1 1 3 4 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The `rank` function gets you part of the way, but doesn't do what you're asking for:

```
rank(x, ties.method="min")
# [1] 1 1 5 7 3 5 3
```

A simpler approach is to use `factor` and `as.numeric` instead:

```
as.numeric(factor(x, sort(unique(x))))
# [1] 1 1 3 4 2 3 2
```

Comment: I was afraid it was something like that.